# Обработка неверных данных в табличном редакторе

Tags: c++, c++builder

Есть текстовый редактор. Нужно сделать следующее: если в ячейку ввели неправильные данные, в ячейку записывается "#" и номер ошибки. Как сделать, чтобы не вылетала ошибка компиляции или другая, а просто в ячейку поступал шарпик?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А причем тут ошибка компиляции? Ячейки у Вас как реализованы? Я мог бы предположить примерно такой код:

```
 Cell_2D x; // наша ячейка

 ret = Validate(x.data); // проверили данные, которые реально в ячейке.
 if (ret)
 {
    x.show_data = Evaluate(x); //x.show_data - отображаемые данные,
       // в виде строки (CString, std::string или что-то подобное)
 }
 else
 {
    x.show_data = "#" + ret; // отобразили #, внутренние данные ячейки не трогаем.
 }
```

Comment: Вот допустим у меня условие проверяется через функцию IntToStr и если входные данные не являются типу int, то выскакивает ошибка. Нужно чтобы данные проверялись до подхода на эту функцию и  даная ошибка не выскакивает. Ячейки реализованы класом StringGrid.

Comment: Вариантов два.

1. разбираете вручную что есть что
2. используете обработку ошибок. Получается что-то в духе
`   try
    {
       IntToStr();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
       //случилось что-то нехорошее.
    }`

Comment: Вот пример ловли ошибки с разъяснением почему она не ловилась - http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/delphi/2160280.flat.aspx